# Svg image grayscale for IE11

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a css or jquery solution to grayscale an .svg in img tag. This works for all browsers except IE11.

```css
img {
  max-width:400px;
  max-height: 200px;
  filter: brightness(0.7) grayscale(1);
    webkit-filter: brightness(0.7) grayscale(1);
   -webkit-filter: brightness(0.7) grayscale(1);
   }
 img:hover {
 filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://downloadfreesvgicons.com/icons/shape-icons/svg-red-heart-icon-1/svg-red-heart-icon-1.svg">
```

Comment: Provide snippet with correct image

Comment: I updated the image.